# CAPL passing a struct as method parameter

Tags: methods, struct, parameter-passing, capl

I need to define a struct in CANoe, afterwards I need to create system variables of those structs, that’s ok but I need to use the struct as parameter to have a single method for all struct. for example:

I’ve highlighted in bold "** struct myStruct**" the part that is not working in this moment.

```
void TestMethod(**struct myStruct**, char myText[])
{
   sysSetVariableString(sysvarMember::VarNamespace::structVar.textField, myText);
}
```

CANoe struct creation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9jVG.png)

How is the right syntaxis to send a struct object as parameter in a method?

Thank you very much.

I've try to use the Datatype "VarNamespace::sctructVar" but is not working.
I've check the CAPL documentation but doesn't use struct as argument in any example.

I expect to be able to create methods with the struct data type as argument.

Comment: That is not a struct but a systemvariable of type struct. SysVars of type struct are not supported as CAPL parameters. As all sysvars are "global", what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to create s struct to store variable data. I want to define the maximun and minimun value of a variable and want to create a generic method to set up this values, and afterwards other method to check id the variable is out range (i plan to call this methods in the on message, on sysvar_change or on signal....).

Comment: What I want to point out. There is always exactly one instance of a system variable (they are global singletons). So there is no real need to pass it as a parameter. However, when you use a struct (defined in CAPL), you can have multiple instances of that struct. The latter can simply be used as a parameter of a CAPL function. Which way is feasible depends on your use case.

Comment: I get it now, i'll think wich option is better for my case. Thanks a lot!